# mySQL SELECT FROM table WHERE ... AND ... AND ... AND

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table "articles" with columns and data:

```
article_id     title               body
1            This is the title   This is the body text
2            Another title       Another body text
```

Another table "category" with columns and data:

```
category_id    category
1              localnews
2              visible
3              first10
```

And a table "categories" with columns and data:

```
categories_id   article_id  category_id
1               1           1
2               1           2
3               1           3
4               2           1
5               2           3
```

I want to SELECT the row(s) WHERE categories.category_id = 1 AND =2 AND =3

I'm using:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.body, 
categories.article_id, categories.category_id 
FROM articles, categories 
WHERE articles.article_id = categories.article_id 
AND categories.article_id = 1 
AND categories.article_id = 2 
AND categories.article_id = 3
```

but it doesn't work. Obviously mySQL needs another syntax. 
Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: Your query is equivalent to "I want a red car that has a blue colour and that has a yellow colour"

Comment: he is looking for articles which are in **all** 3 categories

Comment: The relational operator you require is [division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29), popularly known as ["the supplier who supplies all parts"](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm). Considerations include whether [exact division or with remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) and how to handle and empty divisor.

Comment: From the table "articles" I want to select only the first entry which belongs to ALL three "categories" i.e. localnews, visible and first10. As shown in table categories the article_id = 1 has category_id 1 and 2 and 3 while the second article has not the "visible" category and I don't want to select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   Articles.article_id, 
   COUNT( Categories.article_id ) AS total 
FROM CategoryArticles 
LEFT JOIN Articles USING (article_id)
WHERE 
   CategoryArticles.category_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY CategoryArticles.article_id
HAVING  total = 3
```

I used a bit different names for table because in your example the distinction between `category` and `categories` is hard to notice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This returns article_id  total
1          3 but it doesn't return the title and the body.

Comment: @Kostas , well , then change what is between `SELECT` and `FROM` ... i thought you knew how to choose which columns to select

Comment: Right! I changed it to SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.body, COUNT( categories.article_id ) AS total
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN articles
USING ( article_id )
WHERE categories.category_id
IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
GROUP BY categories.article_id
HAVING total =3
and it works

Answer (score 1):

An column of a row cannot be 1, 2 or 3 *at the same time*, which is what `AND` stipulates. Use `OR` in your `WHERE` condition. Better yet - for readability - you can use `IN`:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE `categories`.`article_id` IN(1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think IN is a "shorthand" for "OR" but I need something like IN but a "shorthand" for "AND".

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the commonly used IN() and using a HAVING count, I would be interested in the performance difference by doing a multiple-join as follows...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      articles.article_id, 
      articles.title, 
      articles.body
   FROM 
      categories c1
         JOIN articles
            on c1.article_id = articles.article_id
         JOIN categories c2
            on c1.article_id = c2.article_id
           AND c2.category_id = 2
         JOIN categories c3
            on c1.article_id = c3.article_id
           AND c3.category_id = 3
  WHERE
     c1.Category_ID = 1
```

Yes, this may look obscure, but lets think about it... by doing a join FIRST on the categories table where ONE of your specific categories -- THIS FIRST FROM instance of categories should be representative of whichever category would have the smallest granularity.  Ex: Your categories of Local News, Visible and First 10.  Local news would probably have the most entries, while Visible and First 10 would have even less... of those, which would have even the smallest number of records.  Use THIS category as the where clause.

So, say you have 100,000 articles, and 90,000 are in local news, 45,000 in Visible, and 12,000 in First 10.  By starting your query on only those in the 12,000, you are eliminating most of the data.

By then joining to the articles table, and categories AGAIN as alias C2 and C3 respectively based on the other conditions, if found, done, if not, its excluded.

Again, I'm wondering the performance impact.  I would also have a compound index on the categories table on both (article_id, category_id)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This query returns exactly what I want. For the time being the entries are much less than the figures you mention and they are not expected to become so many in the near future.

Comment: what if you want to find articles which belong to 10 specific categories ?

Comment: I suppose I would have to add JOIN-on-ANDs

Answer (score 0):

The value cannot be all three values simultaneously, so you'd better use an `IN` clause in your `WHERE` to define which you want to return. Give you've already got a join condition there, you'd want to move that to an `ON` clause instead as well; ie:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.body, categories.article_id, categories.category_id 
FROM articles
INNER JOIN categories ON articles.article_id = categories.article_id 
WHERE categories.article_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

Of course, you can go to the next step and do:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.body, category.category
FROM articles
INNER JOIN categories ON articles.article_id = categories.article_id 
INNER JOIN category ON categories.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE categories.article_id IN ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

If instead you wanted to show only articles that appear in all three categories, then you could take an approach like:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.body
FROM articles
INNER JOIN categories AS c1
ON articles.article_id = c1.article_id 
AND   c1.category_id = 1
INNER JOIN categories AS c2
ON articles.article_id = c2.article_id 
AND   c2.category_id = 2
INNER JOIN categories AS c3
ON articles.article_id = c3.article_id 
AND   c3.category_id = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both queries return both rows but I want only the first one.

Comment: @Kostas Why do you only want the first one? I don't see that mentioned in your question?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I want the first one because it is in all three categories as shown in the categories table.

Comment: @Kostas It wasn't clear from the original text that that was what you're after -- have added that case as well though.